# condition statement in apply function not work correctly in R

Tags: r, if-statement, apply

I had a dataframe, whose ID column had many duplicated names. So I used table() function to get the frequency of IDs. like this:

```
library(dplyr)
id <- runif(1000,1000,3000) %>% round() %>% as.character()
freq <- rep(1:50,20)
data <- data.frame(id,freq)
GetID <- function(a){
  if (a[2]==1) newid <- a[1] else newid <- paste(a[1],1:a[2],sep = "-");
  return(newid)}
idlist <- data %>% apply(., 1, GetID)
idlist2 <- unlist(idlist) %>% as.data.frame()
```

I wanted to get a new ID vector. If the freq equals 1, the new ID equals the old one. If the freq is larger than 1, the new ID is the old id combined with its order.
However, it seems the if statement didn't work correctly. All of new id had order number.

Comment: 1553-1, 2430-1, 2430-2, 2217-1, 2217-2...
However, what I expected is 1553, 2430-1, 2430-2, 2217-1, 2217-2, 2217-3...

Comment: With set.seed(1), the head of idlist2 is "1531-1" "1744-1" "1744-2" "2146-1" "2146-2" "2146-3". What I expected is "1531" "1744-1" "1744-2" "2146-1" "2146-2" "2146-3"

Comment: @Ronak Shah's answer can solve this problem. But I still don't know what's wrong with my code. It seems the if statement didn't work correctly in apply function.

Comment: I find a solution for this problem. Before the if condition statement, use t <-a[2] %>% as.numeric(). Then put t in the if condition statement instead of a[2]. It seems that there is something wrong for the apply function with condition statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group_by` `id` and if number of rows is greater  than 1 then paste `row_number()` with `id` or just use `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(newID = if(n() > 1) paste(id, row_number(), sep = '-') 
                 else as.character(id)) %>%
  arrange(id)


#    id     freq newID 
#   <chr> <int> <chr> 
# 1 1002     49 1002-1
# 2 1002     31 1002-2
# 3 1003     26 1003  
# 4 1005     11 1005-1
# 5 1005     28 1005-2
# 6 1007     37 1007  
# 7 1013     33 1013  
# 8 1016      7 1016  
# 9 1020     11 1020  
#10 1024     28 1024  
# … with 990 more rows
```

Comment: Wow! Great! Thank you. Your answer can solve this problem. Another question, can you spot the error in my original code？

Comment: I think the code would not work as it is, it would require some changes in the function. Also you are not assigning the values from the function to any column.

Answer (score 1):

do you have to use a function? if not:

```
id <- runif(1000,1000,3000)
freq <- rep(1:50,20)
num <- 1:length(id)
data <- data.frame(num,id,freq)
data2 <- data %>% filter(freq == 1) %>% mutate(newid = id)
data3 <- data %>% filter(freq != 1) %>% mutate(newid = paste(id,freq,sep = "-"))
result <- rbind(data2,data3) %>% arrange(num)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My statement was not clear enough. The new IDs I expected were  like this.  If the freq of an ID(such as 2020) equals 3, the new IDs are 2020-1, 2020-2, 2020-3. If the freq of 2021 equals 1, the new ID is still 2021.